# Wrong answers to algebraic expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is $p= -0.01s^2 + 0.8s + 3.7$, $s$ is given as equalling $30$. The answer should be near $20$, but I am continually getting larger negative numbers because of the first term, but I am not sure how to solve it correctly.

Comment: Hint: order of operations.

Answer (score 2):

$p = -0.01 \times 900 + 0.8 \times 30 + 3.7$

$p = -9 + 24 + 3.7$

$p = 18.7$

Comment: If still any doubt please ask.